# understanding LOCAL and GLOBAL variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

i write this code for shuffle array:

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        if (x === y) { //for dont change arr[i] with arr[i]!!!
            continue;
        }
        temp0 = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp0;
    }
    return arr
}
```

it work correctly.
but my problem is, this function not global, i explain it with a example:

```
    sampleArray=["a", "b", "c", "d"];

    shuffle(sampleArray); //only run function
    console.log (sampleArray); // output NOT shuffled. ==>> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    console.log (shuffle(sampleArray)); //output shuffled. my be ["d", "a", "c", "b"] or ...
```

in main code i cant declare sampleArray nested in shuffle function...

Comment: AFAIK all the variables you're using are global.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the only variable that isn't global is `arr`, since it's a parameter. Everything else is global.

Comment: @VLAZ you're right! That's a parameter. (I didn't spot that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in your code. length NOT lengt. Also, since arrays are passed by reference you don't need a return

```js
function shuffle(arr) {

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        var  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        
        if (x === y) { //for dont change arr[i] with arr[i]!!!
            continue;
        }
        temp0 = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp0;
    }
    
    
}
sampleArray=["a", "b", "c", "d"];



shuffle(sampleArray);


console.log(sampleArray);
```

Comment: yes, work for me. but a question, is this standard code!? a function without return!?. i ask about it because when console.log (shuffle(sampleArray) in console show undefined

Comment: functions don't have to have return statements.  You can add one if you want, but you don't really need it here.

Comment: please introduce to me a reference (with easy English) about type of calls in js @DCR

Answer (score 1):

### `let`, `const` and `var` context

If you do not define your variables with `let`, `const` or `var`, they will be scoped as global variables.

You have in [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/var-let-const/) a good tutorial about javascript variables and scoping.

But resuming:

- If you do not put `let`, `const` or `var` before your variable definition will be always created as a global variable.
- If you use `var` before, the variable will be created as function scoped.
- If you use `let` before, the variable will be block scoped (between two {}).
- If you use `const` before, the same rules of `let` are applied with an exception of you can't reasign a new value to the variable.

### Moreover!

Non-permitive values such as arrays, in javascript, are passed to function as a reference, meaning if you change any array value inside a function, the original variable will change is value as well *(For more info, [check](https://medium.com/@TK_CodeBear/javascript-arrays-pass-by-value-and-thinking-about-memory-fffb7b0bf43) this link)*. This is why your `sampleArray` are being changed: because you change the `arr` variable that references the `sampleArray` in the `shuffle` function.

### Example Time!

For this to work you could do a [deepcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) of the `arr` inside the `shuffle` function like this:

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
    //deep copy
    const deepCopyArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
    for (i = 0; i < deepCopyArray.length; i++) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * deepCopyArray.length);
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * deepCopyArray.length);
        if (x === y) { //for dont change arr[i] with arr[i]!!!
            continue;
        }
        temp0 = deepCopyArray[x];
        deepCopyArray[x] = deepCopyArray[y];
        deepCopyArray[y] = temp0;
    }
    return deepCopyArray
}

sampleArray=["a", "b", "c", "d"];
shuffle(sampleArray); //only run function
console.log (sampleArray); // output NOT shuffled. ==>> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
console.log (shuffle(sampleArray)); //output shuffled. my be ["d", "a", "c", "b"]
```

Comment: @sMohammad14 But the code that you are showing to use does not either  use let, const or var.